# Ill-formed goto jump in C++ with compile-time known-to-be-false condition: is it actually illegal?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, goto

I am learning about some dark corners of C++ and, in particular, about the "forbidden" `goto` and some restrictions on its usage. This question is partially inspired by [Patrice Roy's talk at CppCon 2019 "Some Programming Myths Revisited"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KNqRjzSlUVo) ([link to exact time with a similar example](https://youtu.be/KNqRjzSlUVo?list=PLDmhdaGQ9jF13KkiqpvE0LA0ioz8YV7SI&t=634)).

Note, this is a language lawyer question, and I in no way advocate for the usage of `goto` in this particular example.

---

The following C++ code:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

struct X {
    X() { std::cout<<"X Constructor\n"; }
    ~X() { std::cout<<"X Destructor\n"; }
};

bool maybe_skip() { return std::rand()%10 != 0; }

int main()
{
    if (maybe_skip()) goto here;
    
    X x; // has non-trivial constructor; thus, preventing jumping over itself
    here:
    
    return 0;
}
```

is ill-formed and won't compile. Since `goto` can skip the initialization of `x` of type `X` that has a non-trivial constructor.

Error message from Apple Clang:

> ```
> error: cannot jump from this goto statement to its label
> if (maybe_skip()) goto here;
>                   ^
> note: jump bypasses variable initialization
> X x;
>   ^
> ```

**This is clear to me.**

However, what is not clear, is why the variations of this with the `constexpr` qualifier

```
constexpr bool maybe_skip() { return false; }
```

or even simply going with an always `false` if-condition known in compile-time

```c++
#include <iostream>

struct X {
    X() { std::cout<<"X Constructor\n"; }
    ~X() { std::cout<<"X Destructor\n"; }
};

constexpr bool maybe_skip() { return false; }  // actually cannot skip

int main()
{
    // if constexpr (maybe_skip()) goto here;
    if constexpr (false) goto here;
    
    X x; // has non-trivial constructor; thus, preventing jumping over itself
    here:
    
    return 0;
}
```

is also ill-formed (tried on Apple Clang 11.0.3 and GCC 9.2).

According to [Sec. 9.7 of N4713](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf):

> It is possible to transfer into a block, but not in a way that bypasses declarations with initialization. A program that jumps from a point where a variable with automatic storage duration is not in scope to a point where it is in scope is ill-formed unless the variable has scalar type, class type with a trivial default constructor and a trivial destructor, a cv-qualified version of one of these types, or an array of one of the preceding types and is declared without an initializer (11.6).

So, **does my second version** of the program with `if constexpr (false) goto here;` **actually "jump" in the eyes of the compiler**, even though at the end of the day it would have deleted this "jump" anyway? <s>(`constexpr` in the last case with plain `false` is mostly redundant, but left for consistency)</s>.

I might be missing the exact phrasing or interpretation of the standard, or the "order of the operations" because in my [apparently, faulty] logic, the illegal jump does not and cannot happen.

Comment: Actually, `constexpr` is not "mostly redundant". This is fairly cut and dry with a plain garden-variety `if`: this is ill-formed. Just because the goto can be optimized out doesn't change the requirements that the code must be well-formed, and it's not. `if constexpr` bends the rules, making things that would otherwise be ill-formed go away. This is a good question, why this is still ill-formed with `if constexpr`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik interesting, I did not think of it. Made a small edit.

Comment: Heh! In Visual Studio 2019, MSVC accepts your last code but clang-cl is **really upset** by it: 20 or so lines of 'stack trace', followed by `clang-cl : error : clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)` and then, a few lines later, **clang-cl : message : diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to...**

Comment: You already quoted the code that answers your question . `goto` is a jump statement and it jumps to the corresponding label .  The text does not say anything about whether the jump statement is reachable .

Answer (score 35, accepted):

First of all, the rule about `goto` not being allowed to skip over a nontrivial initialization is a compile-time rule. If a program contains such a `goto`, the compiler is required to issue a diagnostic.

Now we turn to the question of whether `if constexpr` can "delete" the offending `goto` statement and thereby erase the violation. The answer is: only under certain conditions. The only situation where the discarded substatement is "truly eliminated" (so to speak) is when the `if constexpr` is inside a template and we are instantiating the last template after which the condition is no longer dependent, and at that point the condition is found to be `false` (C++17 [stmt.if]/2). In this case the discarded substatement is *not instantiated*. For example:

```
template <int x>
struct Foo {
    template <int y>
    void bar() {
        if constexpr (x == 0) {
            // (*)
        }
        if constexpr (x == 0 && y == 0) {
            // (**)
        }
    }
};
```

Here, `(*)` will be eliminated when `Foo` is instantiated (giving `x` a concrete value). `(**)` will be eliminated when `bar()` is instantiated (giving `y` a concrete value) since at that point, the enclosing class template must have already been instantiated (thus `x` is already known).

A discarded substatement that is not eliminated during template instantiation (either because it is not inside a template at all, or because the condition is not dependent) is still "compiled", except that:

- the entities referenced therein are not odr-used (C++17 [basic.def.odr]/4);
- any `return` statements located therein do not participate in return type deduction (C++17 [dcl.spec.auto]/2).

Neither of these two rules will prevent a compilation error in the case of a `goto` that skips over a variable with nontrivial initialization. In other words, the only time when a `goto` inside a discarded substatement, that skips over a nontrivial initialization, will *not* cause a compilation error is when the `goto` statement "never becomes real" in the first place due to being discarded during the step in template instantiation that would normally create it concretely. Any other `goto` statements are not saved by either of the two exceptions above (since the issue is not with odr-use, nor return type deduction).

Thus, when (similarly to your example) we have the following not inside any template:

```
// Example 1
if constexpr (false) goto here;
X x;
here:;
```

Therefore, the `goto` statement is already concrete, and the program is ill-formed. In Example 2:

```
// Example 2
template <class T>
void foo() {
    if constexpr (false) goto here;
    X x;
    here:;
}
```

if `foo<T>` were to be instantiated (with any argument for `T`), then the `goto` statement would be instantiated (resulting in a compilation error). The `if constexpr` would not protect it from instantiation, because the condition doesn't depend on any template parameters. In fact, in example 2, **even if `foo` is never instantiated**, the program is ill-formed NDR (*i.e.*, the compiler may be able to figure out that it will always cause an error regardless of what `T` is, and thus diagnose this even before instantiation) (C++17 [temp.res]/8.

Now let's consider example 3:

```
// Example 3
template <class T>
void foo() {
    if constexpr (false) goto here;
    T t;
    here:;
}
```

the program will be well-formed if, say, we only instantiate `foo<int>`. When `foo<int>` is instantiated, the variable skipped over has trivial initialization and destruction, and there is no problem. However, if `foo<X>` were to be instantiated, then an error would occur at that point: the whole body including the `goto` statement (which skips over the initialization of an `X`) would be instantiated at that point. Because the condition is not dependent, the `goto` statement is not protected from instantiation; one `goto` statement is created every time a specialization of `foo` is instantiated.

Let's consider example 4 with a dependent condition:

```
// Example 4
template <int n>
void foo() {
    if constexpr (n == 0) goto here;
    X x;
    here:;
}
```

Prior to instantiation, the program contains a `goto` statement only in the syntactic sense; semantic rules such as [stmt.dcl]/3 (the prohibition on skipping over an initialization) are not applied yet. And, in fact, if we only instantiate `foo<1>`, then the `goto` statement is still not instantiated and [stmt.dcl]/3 is still not triggered. However, regardless of whether the `goto` is ever instantiated at all, it remains true that *if* it were to be instantiated, it would always be ill-formed. [temp.res]/8 says the program is ill-formed NDR if the `goto` statement is never instantiated (either because `foo` itself is never instantiated, or the specialization `foo<0>` is never instantiated). If instantiation of `foo<0>` occurs, then it's just ill-formed (diagnostic *is* required).

Finally:

```
// Example 5
template <class T>
void foo() {
    if constexpr (std::is_trivially_default_constructible_v<T> &&
                  std::is_trivially_destructible_v<T>) goto here;
    T t;
    here:;
}
```

Example 5 is well-formed regardless of whether `T` happens to be `int` or `X`. When `foo<X>` is instantiated, because the condition depends on `T`, [stmt.if]/2 kicks in. When the body of `foo<X>` is being instantiated, the `goto` statement is *not* instantiated; it exists only in a syntactic sense and [stmt.dcl]/3 is not violated because *there is no `goto` statement*. As soon as the initialization statement "`X t;`" is instantiated, the `goto` statement disappears at the same time, so there is no problem. And of course, if `foo<int>` is instantiated, whereupon the `goto` statement *is* instantiated, it only skips over the initialization of an `int`, and there is no problem.

Comment: I’m not actually sure which of our answers is more correct.  The last example with a dependent type is really what’s interesting: what if the variable depends only on an enclosing class template’s template parameter, but the condition depends on the function’s template parameters?  Is the constexpr if then invalid per [temp.res]/8?

Comment: @DavisHerring hmm, and I thought that I went into a dark corner of C++.

Answer (score 3):

The word “program” refers to the **static** entity made of code (“process” is the usual word for the dynamic entity, although the standard tends to merely refer to “execution”).  Similarly, “ill-formed” is a static property; “undefined behavior” is used to describe “runtime errors”.

`if constexpr` doesn’t change this analysis simply because no rule says so: `if constexpr` affects return type deduction (courtesy of [dcl.spec.auto.general]), the necessity of definitions ([basic.def.odr]), and instantiation ([stmt.if] itself), but that’s all.  It’s not defined to **“omit”** one of its branches like `#if`, which is a common source of confusion when people put something like `static_assert(false);` or a simple syntax error into one side.

It may be useful to know that C++23 is in the process of changing the quoted sentence to read

> Then, all variables that are active at Q but not at P are initialized in declaration order; unless all such variables have vacuous initialization ([basic.life]), the transfer of control shall not be a jump<sup>[…]</sup>.

which is perhaps a bit less easy to read as describing a dynamic prohibition (since the “are initialized in declaration order” is a static description of the behavior, just like the statement that the operand of `++` “is modified”).

Comment: I don't fully understand this. So this is ill-formed? Is a diagnostic required? Also, are you saying that `#if 0 goto here; #endif` is fine?

Comment: @cigien: Yes, ill-formed with a required diagnostic, and the `#if 0` version is fine because the tokens never become a jump statement at all.